# How do I set TeamCity build status from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, build, teamcity, status

I am trying to set the status of a Team City build from Powershell. I found how to do it from Windows cmd:

```
##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE' text='A non-standard URL has been committed to SVN']
EXIT 1
```

It works perfectly when running as a cmd; however, I have a need to do this in a Powershell script. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I tried it as-is in Powershell, but the pound sign acts like a comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The `#` sing is start of the single line comment, you have to make it regular string. Just put it into quotes:

```
"##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE' text='A non-standard URL has been committed to SVN']"
exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. It works great! I was simply missing quotes around the whole thing:

[Here is the solution to my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674163/teamcity-command-line-build-runner-how-to-make-the-build-fail)

Answer (score 0):

After Version 7.1, you can use buildProblem to report a failure and it will display the failure text instead of just "exit 1"

> "##teamcity[buildProblem description='A non-standard URL has
>   been committed to SVN']"